# The updated array in local storage cannot be used in the code. -p5.js

Tags: javascript, local-storage, processing, p5.js

There are two arrays in this code. Initially, the first of these arrays contains numbers 1-10, while the other array has no numbers. I want the generated random number to be selected from the non-intersecting numbers between array1 and array2. The random number generated in the code is pushed to array2 and the information of array2 is stored in local storage. Although array2 is updated (I checked with the print(array2) method), there is no random number generation based on the updated version of array2.

```
function preload(){
let array1 = [];
let array2 = [];  
  
for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    array1.push(i);
  }
  
  
 
  
  // Find non-intersecting numbers between the two arrays
  let NIM = array1.filter(num => !array2.includes(num));
  
  // Choose a random number from the non-intersecting numbers
  let randomIndex = floor(random(NIM.length));
  let randeg = NIM[randomIndex];
img = loadImage("https://ipfs.filebase.io/ipfs/" + monArray[randeg]);

  
  

  if (localStorage.getItem('array2')) {
    array2 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('array2'));
  }
  
  // Generate and push a random number to the array
  
  array2.push(randeg);
  
  // Save the updated array data to localStorage
  localStorage.setItem('array2', JSON.stringify(array2));
 

  print(NIM);
  print(array2);
  
}
```

When array2 contains numbers as below, the selection is made between non-intersecting numbers. So the code works fine.

```
let array1 = [];
let array2 = [];  
  
for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    array1.push(i);
  }
  
  // Fill array2 with numbers from 5 to 10
  for (let i = 5; i <= 580; i++) {
  array2.push(i);
}
  
 
  
  // Find non-intersecting numbers between the two arrays
  let NIM = array1.filter(num => !array2.includes(num));
  
  // Choose a random number from the non-intersecting numbers
  let randomIndex = floor(random(NIM.length));
  let randeg = NIM[randomIndex];
img = loadImage("https://ipfs.filebase.io/ipfs/" + monArray[randeg]);
```

I would appreciate it if you could help me solve this problem.

I tried changing the ordering, but this time the generated random number cannot be read by the code.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve with this, but usually it makes much more sense to use _one_ array, and shuffle that - then you can pick random, non-repeating elements out of that one by one.

Comment: This is a generative art piece that I created for ArtBlocks and it'll be on-chain. I would like to create randomized image selection for this serie. It'll be challenging for me to solve backend issues so I'm trying different approaches for having different options because I don't know if it's possibble or not to doing this.

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what you are talking about there.

Comment: Looks like this is an [XY question](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem), what is it you're trying to do exactly? Pick any random numbers?